# Firefox ignores border top left radius on table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have following CSS3 Rules:

```
.acpTable thead tr th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 9px;
}

.acpTable thead tr th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
}
```

In DOM I have a Table with the class `acpTable` and added via jQuery a `tHead` element.
In current Chrome browser it works, in current firefox not. What am I doing wrong?

The selectors work, I've tested with "background: green" and the correct cells would be colored.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

The developer toolbar shows it's computed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the radius on the parents:

```
.acpTable,                              /* The Table */
.acpTable thead,                        /* The Head */
.acpTable thead tr:first-child,         /* The Row */
.acpTable thead tr th:first-child {     /* The Content */
    border-top-left-radius: 9px;
}
```

You must set your Table to `border-collapse: collapse;` ([MOZ Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius)):

> but UA are not required to apply to table undinline-table Elemente when border-collapse ist collapse. The behavior on internal table Elemente ist undefined for the moment.

Comment: Testet - it doesnt work on firefox with this. In Chrome it works

Comment: Not all browsers can render it correct, thats the trick: Define the parents with the radius. But why you dont use `border-radius: 9px 0 0 0;` instead of `border-top-left-radius: 9px;`?

Comment: Oderwise use browserbased names like `-moz-border-radius-topleft: 9px;`

Comment: i seen border-radius: a b c d not the first time. - It doenst work with all definitions: <img src="http://puu.sh/8qZDh/e4792045ba.png">

Comment: I´ve found my error - i have setted the color to the wrong element (the tr element) - why it works for chrome i dont know. ive setted the background color rule to the th elements, now it works in firefox too.